# Insert PHP array and string in MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query which is working fine in inputting the arrays `$stid` and `$attendance_status`. However, I also want to populate the column called SCH_TIMESLOT with a fixed number `22` or eventually a string value which is the same for all records. I am getting an error stating:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '22' at line 2

This is my query:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($attendance_status);$i++){
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO `ATTENDANCE` (`ID`, `STUDENT_ID`, `ATTENDANCE`, `SCH_TIMESLOT`) VALUES
   (NULL, $stid[$i], $attendance_status[$i]), 22") or die (mysql_error());
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Please try '22' once. It can solve your problem.

Comment: You have a closing brace in the wrong place, should be :`(NULL, $stid[$i], $attendance_status[$i], 22)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed out 22 from your VALUES brackets. It has to be inside.

```
<?php
for($i=0;$i<count($attendance_status);$i++){
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO `ATTENDANCE` (`ID`, `STUDENT_ID`, `ATTENDANCE`, `SCH_TIMESLOT`) VALUES
(NULL, $stid[$i], $attendance_status[$i], 22)") or die (mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error.

`$stid[$i], $attendance_status[$i]), 22")` you are closing the brackets before 22

Try it like this

```
"INSERT INTO `ATTENDANCE` (`ID`, `STUDENT_ID`, `ATTENDANCE`, `SCH_TIMESLOT`)    
    VALUES
 (NULL, $stid[$i], $attendance_status[$i], 22)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i replace ")" before "22" and move it after.

```
for($i=0;$i<count($attendance_status);$i++){
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO `ATTENDANCE` (`ID`, `STUDENT_ID`, `ATTENDANCE`, `SCH_TIMESLOT`) VALUES
   (NULL, $stid[$i], $attendance_status[$i], 22)") or die (mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your sql query as below

```
for($i=0;$i<count($attendance_status);$i++){
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO `ATTENDANCE` (`ID`, `STUDENT_ID`, `ATTENDANCE`, `SCH_TIMESLOT`) VALUES `(NULL, $stid[$i], $attendance_status[$i], 22") or die (mysql_error());`
```